# How can I execute an specifc SQL in Grails/GORM/Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, grails-orm

I have domains like that in Grails:

```
class Questao {

    static transients = [ "tags" ]

    String enunciado
    Double valorQuestao
    byte[] imagem
    public enum Tipo {
        ALTERNATIVAS,
        VF,
        SUBJETIVA
    }

    Tipo tipoQuestao

    static hasMany = [alternativas:Alternativas, assuntos: QuestaoAssunto, provas: Prova]

    static belongsTo = [Prova]

    static mapping = { enunciado type: 'text'}

    static constraints = {
        imagem nullable: true, maxSize: 160384
        alternativas nullable: true
    }
}

class QuestaoAssunto {

    Questao questao
    Assunto assunto

    static belongsTo = [Questao,Assunto]

}
class Assunto {

    String titulo

    static hasMany = [questoes:QuestaoAssunto]

    static belongsTo = [Questao]
}
```

and i need to execute this SQL:

```
select q.* from questao_assunto qa join questao q on q.id=qa.questao_id where assunto_id in (:assuntos_id) and q.tipo_questao = 'SUBJETIVA' GROUP BY q.id order by rand() limit 1;
```

:assuntos_id is an array like [5,6]

how can make this??

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to execute SQL from a service. The same approach can be used in a controller:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
import groovy.sql.GroovyRowResult

class SomeService {

    // Reference to default datasource.
    def dataSource

    List<GroovyRowResult> executeQuery(assuntosId) {

        final String query = '''\
                select q.* 
                from questao_assunto qa 
                join questao q on q.id=qa.questao_id 
                where assunto_id in (:assuntos_id) 
                and q.tipo_questao = 'SUBJETIVA' 
                group by q.id 
                order by rand() 
                limit 1
        '''

        // Create new Groovy SQL instance with injected DataSource.
        final Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)

        final results = sql.rows(query, assuntos_id: assuntosId)
        results
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a reason to define the join-table by yourself, but my approach would be:

```
class Questao {

    static transients = [ "tags" ]

    String enunciado
    Double valorQuestao
    byte[] imagem
    public enum Tipo { ALTERNATIVAS, VF, SUBJETIVA }

    Tipo tipoQuestao

    static hasMany = [assuntos: Assunto]

    static mapping = { 
        enunciado type: 'text'
        assuntos joinTable:[name:"questao_assunto", key:'assunto_id' ]
    }

    static constraints = {
        imagem nullable: true, maxSize: 160384
    }
}

class Assunto {

    String titulo

    static hasMany = [questoes:Questao]

    static belongsTo = [Questao]

    static mapping = {
        questoes joinTable:[name:"questao_assunto", key:'questao_id' ]
    }
}
```

and to execute the SQL, I would try it like the following:

```
def records = Questao.findAll { 
    tipoQuestao == Questao.Tipo.SUBJETIVA 
    && assuntos { id in [1 as long,2 as long,3 as long] } 
}
```

or if you would like to order and limit by 1

```
def records = Questao.find(order: 'xxx') { ... }
```